# Python 3.9 - Multithreading with queues

Tags: python, multithreading, queue

I think this may be a simple question but I just can't seem to get my head around this. Consider the below sample code.

```
def 1_processing(search_query, q):
    ''' Do some data http data fetching using Python 'Requests' - may take 5 to 20 seconds'''
    q.put(a)
    q.put(b)
    ''' Two to three items to be put into the queue'''

def 2_processing(search_query, q):
    ''' Do some http data fetching using Python 'Requests' - may take 5 to 20 seconds'''
    q.put(x)
    q.put(y)
    q.put(z)
    ''' Two to three items to be put into the queue'''


q = queue.Queue()

''' Start the threads asynchronously'''
t1 = threading.Thread(target=1_processing, args=('search_query', q))
t2 = threading.Thread(target=2_processing, args=('search_query', q))
t1.start()
t2.start()
```

I am trying to run two asynchronous processes and then consume the data (through queues) as soon as it is received without having to wait for either or both of the processes to complete.

How do I consume the queue data as soon as it is received?

I know that I can do a simple q.get() but I don't know the queue size in advance. I also do not want to join (t1.join, t2.join()) the processes because that would mean the program will take too long and not display the data as soon as it is received. I want to be able to display data as soon as it is received AND also know when the processes have completed WHILE I am getting  the data from the queues.

Thanks.

Comment: You may have misunderstood the Queue paradigm. I'll put together an example and post as an Answer shortly

Comment: Python methods and, neither variables can't start with numbers or any special characters

Answer (score 1):

queue.Queue is a very useful class as it not only provides a mechanism for passing data between threads but also (optionally) effectively limits the number of concurrent threads. Queue is a FIFO queue. If constructed with no arguments then its size is unlimited (subject to memory constraints). However, if constructed with an integer parameter, that value limits the number of items that can be on the queue at any point in time. If the queue is full, the put() function will block until space is available. Here's a trivial example:-

```
import queue
import threading

Q = queue.Queue(2)  # limit concurrent threads to 2


def func1(p):
    print(f'{p} -> {Q.get()}')


T = []

for i in range(10):
    t = threading.Thread(target=func1, args=('foo',)) # construct the thread
    Q.put(i) # place a value on the queue - may block
    T.append(t) # add thread reference to list for join later
    t.start() # start the thread

[t.join() for t in T] # wait for all threads to terminate
```

Comment: Thanks @DarkKnight, I may well have misunderstood how Queues are supposed to be used. Let me make sense of your example. Please bear with me as I am still fairly new to all this!